# How to limit data while showing from a json file in a horizontal slide circularly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, slider

Hi i am trying to show json data in a local file into a horizontal slider. If i kept statically images like below slide is working perfectly.

```
<ul id="slider_th">
            <li><img id="1" src="assets/img/employee/1.jpg" width="135" height="135" alt=""></li>
            <li><img id="2" src="assets/img/employee/2.jpg" width="135" height="135" alt=""></li>
            <li><img id="3" src="assets/img/employee/3.jpg" width="135" height="135" alt=""></li>
            <li><img id="4" src="assets/img/employee/4.jpg" width="135" height="135" alt=""></li>
            <li><img id="5" src="assets/img/employee/5.jpg" width="135" height="135" alt=""></li>
            <li><img id="6" src="assets/img/employee/6.jpg" width="135" height="135" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

Now i am trying to show data from a local json file using JQuery like below at a time 5 images. But i had 6 images to show. Here comes i have two problems.

1. I am able to show 5 images using slice method in JQuery. But slider is not working.
2. After 6th image i need to show first 4 images. I mean circularly it should run.

   ```
    $.getJSON( "assets/js/data.json" , function( result ){
   $.each(result.employees.employee.slice(0,5), function(key, field){
       $('#slider_th').append('<li style="overflow: hidden; float: left; width: 141px; height: 144px;"><img id="emp_image_'+field.id+'" src="'+field.image+'" width="135" height="135" alt="'+field.name+'">');            
   });
    });
   ```

How to make circular the slider and one more thing i am using

> jcarousellite_1.0.1.pack.js

plugin in JQuery

Comment: Where do you initialize the slider? Good change it's already initialized before you alter the DOM.

Comment: are you clear or any doubt?